# Python Azure function app in cd/ci pipelines getting build but in azure portal couldnt see the files

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cd

I am trying to deploy the azure function app through cd/ci pipelines

when I am trying deploy python azure function app with zip file, I couldn't see the files in portal but the build was successful

The build and release was successful but I could see the files in portal

This is my yaml file

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- bash: |
   if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
   then
       dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
   fi
  displayName: 'Build extensions'

- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.6

- bash: 'pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt'
  displayName: 'Install Application Dependencies'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

The release was successful , but couldnt see the files in azure portal

I couldnt paste the img here to show the azure portal

Comment: Hi Kumar, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Comment: yeah , I followed the same steps but don't know ., with zip file the function app is not getting registered

Answer (score 0):

You can see Azure function file on Function ->Development section.

1. Function create on VS Code

[image]

2. Azure devOps CI/CD
   [image]
3. check function file on azure portal.
   [image]

Ref. the link to explore more on [**How to view Azure function files deployed**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/30741/how-to-view-azure-function-files-deployed.html). by markxa answer.

Comment: Thanks, I need to deploy the function through cd/ci pipelines for continuous integration. So I am trying to deploy through the pipeline but the zip deploy is not working. The build was successful but couldnt see the files in function tab in azure portal. If you have any suggestion regarding to pipelines please share

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find CD part in your question.

***CI pipeline:***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

#CI step.
steps:

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azurefunction'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

***CD pipeline:***

```
#Trigger and pool definition here.

steps:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'c6358b04-e91a-4bd1-a894-1adb543134d6'
    pipeline: '195'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
- script: |
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'xxx'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azurefunction'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.9'
```

My Repo structure:

[image]

Successfully on my side:

[image]